# Question on asymptotes

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that has an asymptote at $- \infty$ of the type $y=\lambda x + \beta$. According to trigonometry $\lambda=\tan{\theta}$ for a very small value of x at the point $P(k,f(k))$ near $- \infty$. So $$\lambda =\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} $$

Is it correct to state that $\lambda = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f'(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **provided that** the limit of the derivative exists.

Comment: I can't understand the downvote. The question is whether $\lambda$ coincides with the limit of the first derivative, and this follows at once from De l'Hospital's theorem, provided that $f'$ has a limit at $-\infty$.

Comment: +1 yes, the limit of the derivative need not exist (e.g $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}$ ).

Comment: When I downvoted this answer, the question asked whether $\lambda = f'(k) = \lim_{x\to-\infty}f'(x)$ where $k$ is a large negative number (I think that's what $k$ is meant to be, it's not exactly clear as written). There is in general no $k$ with this property. The question has been edited since then to remove the first of these equalities.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that $\lambda = \lim_{x\to-\infty}f'(x)$ in this situation but it's not true  that $\lambda = f'(k)$ for some $k\in\mathbb R$.

Consider, for example, $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x+1}$. This has an asymptote at $-\infty$ of slope $\lambda=1$. We have $f'(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$, and so $f'(k)\neq 1$ for all $k\in\mathbb R$, since $\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\neq 0$ for all $k$.

This example also shows that in general there is no $k$ with $\lambda = \frac{f(k)}{k}$: otherwise we would have $1 = \frac{x}{x+1}$, and multiplying this out we'd get $x = x+1$ which is impossible.